# How to create MD5 hash with HMAC module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, md5, hmac

Using Google + Bing didn't yield an answer to what should be a simple question:

How are you supposed to use the HMAC module in Ruby to create a HMAC with MD5 (that uses a secret)?

The HMAC docs seem awfully thin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following gem should be installed: 'ruby-hmac'

```
$ irb
>> require 'hmac-md5'
=> true
>> HMAC::MD5.new("abc").digest
=> "\324\035\214\331\217\000\262\004\351\200\t\230\354\370B~"
>> HMAC::MD5.new("abc").hexdigest
=> "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
>>
```

Comment: thanks.

to include a secret, is right to do the following?

HMAC::MD5.new(SECRET + "abc").digest

Comment: Probably you just want HMAC::MD5.new(SECRET).digest

Answer (score 14):

This should be the easiest way:

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('md5'), secret_key, your_data)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
HMAC::MD5.new(shared_key).update(data).hexdigest
```

Answer (score 4):

In 2020 this is how I did it:

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("MD5", secret_key, your_data)
```

Ruby documentation is available here: [OpenSSL::HMAC](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Probably you just want HMAC::MD5.new(SECRET).digest

Lookup "salting" a hash first. It depends on your usage, but adding a fixed string does help by making your hashes different than the hashes from other apps. Thus, a dictionary attack is harder. But that's just generally speaking.

Answer (score -1):

http://betterlogic.com/roger/?p=152

no?

Or I remember toying with it inside one of our Gems so maybe you can reverse engineer from it?

http://github.com/appoxy/aws/tree/master

Hope this helps.

Chad