# HMAC (hash-based message authentication code, aka data signing) in Mathematica

Tags: authentication, hash, code-signing, wolfram-mathematica

It seems there's an implementation of HMAC in every language under the sun. (See below.)
And the algorithm is quite straightforward:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Has anyone implemented it in Mathematica?

Here are pointers to implementations in other languages:

- http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php
- [Objective-C sample code for HMAC-SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756492/objective-c-sample-code-for-hmac-sha1)
- [How to create MD5 hash with HMAC module in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359624/how-to-create-md5-hash-with-hmac-module-in-ruby)
- [java equivalent to php's hmac-SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609899/java-equivalent-to-phps-hmac-sha1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my implementation:

First some utility functions:

```
(* Pad the string s with x on the right/left so it has length n. *)
strpadr[s_, n_, x_] := StringJoin@PadRight[Characters[s], n, x]
strpadl[s_, n_, x_] := StringJoin@PadLeft[Characters[s], n, x]

(* hex representation; optionally pad to length n with zeros *)
hex[x_, n_:Null]:= If[n===Null, Identity, strpadl[#,n,"0"]&]@IntegerString[x,16]

(* parse hex representation (return an integer) *)
unhex[x_] := FromDigits[x, 16]

(* Concatenate all the arguments as strings (if they're not already). *)
cat = StringJoin @@ (ToString /@ {##}) &;

(* Takes a string like "xy" and returns the hex representation (also a string, 
   twice as long) of the bytes (ascii codes). *)
tobytes[s_] := cat @@ (hex[#, 2] & /@ ToCharacterCode[s])

(* Takes a length n string like "0a10" and returns a length n/2 string where in 
   this example the first character is whatever has ascii code 10 ("a" in hex) 
   and the second is whatever has ascii code 16 ("10" in hex). *)
frombytes[hs_] := FromCharacterCode[unhex /@ cat@@@Partition[Characters[hs], 2]]

(* Bitwise-xor of two integers given in hex. *)
hexbitxor[a_String, b_String] := hex@BitXor[unhex@a, unhex@b]

(* Repeat the string s, n times. *)
strrpt[s_, n_] := cat @@ ConstantArray[s, n]

(* Byte length of a hex string is half the string length. *)
bytelen[s_] := Ceiling[StringLength[s]/2]
```

Implementing the basic hash functions in Mathematica is not quite trivial.  See this question:
[Cryptographic hash (sha1 or md5) of data given as a string in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854491/cryptographic-hash).

```
(* FileHash is the only way to hash data given as a string in Mma. *)
hash[s_String, h_:"SHA"] := Module[{stream = StringToStream[s], result},
  result = FileHash[stream, h];
  Close[stream];
  hex@result];
sha1[s_] := hash[s]
md5[s_] := hash[s, "MD5"]
```

Finally, here's the hmac function:

```
(* Return the hmac digest using hash function h for string s with key k. *)
hmac[s_, k_, h_:sha1] := Module[{b, key, ipad, opad},
  b = 64; (* block size for both md5 and sha1 *)
  key = tobytes[k];
  key = If[bytelen[key] > b, h[frombytes@key], key];
  key = strpadr[key, 2 b, "0"];
  ipad = hexbitxor[strrpt["36", b], key];
  opad = hexbitxor[strrpt["5c", b], key];
  h[frombytes[opad <> h[frombytes[ipad <> tobytes@s]]]]]
```

I confirmed that this matches all the examples provided in [RFC 2104](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104.html).  For example:

```
hmac["what do ya want for nothing?", "Jefe", md5]
```

returns

```
"750c783e6ab0b503eaa86e310a5db738"
```