# Cryptographic hash (sha1 or md5) of data given as a string in Mathematica

Tags: hash, cryptography, wolfram-mathematica

The sha1 hash of "abc" is

```
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
```

The only way to get Mathematica to tell you that with its `Hash` function is

```
Hash[abc, "SHA"]   // IntegerString[#, 16]&
```

(The IntegerString thing is just to output it in hex like most implementations do.)

Note that

```
Hash["abc", "SHA"]
```

gives the hash of "\"abc\"" -- not what you want!
In fact, the only reason we could get the correct hash of "abc" was because the Mathematica representation of the symbol `abc` happens to be the string "abc".
For the vast majority of strings, this will not be the case.

So how do you take the hash of an arbitrary string in Mathematica?

Comment: Note that Hash changed in version 8 of Mathematica so that hashes of strings are now the same as in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it less kludgily by using `StringToStream` and the fact that `FileHash` can take an input stream as an argument. Then your `sha1` function becomes:

```
sha1[s_String] := Module[{stream = StringToStream[s], hash},
  hash = FileHash[stream,"SHA"];
  Close[stream];
  hash]
```

Comment: This solution even more correct because `Hash` uses `StringToStream` and `ToString` itself as one may see with `Trace[Hash["abc", "SHA"], _StringToStream | _ToString, TraceInternal -> True]`. And unfortunately it uses Java extensively...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a kludge that works.  Write the string to a temp file and use `FileHash`:

```
sha1[s_String] := Module[{stream, file, hash},
  stream = OpenWrite[];
  WriteString[stream, s];
  file = Close[stream];
  hash = FileHash[file, "SHA"];
  DeleteFile[file];
  hash]
```

You might also want to define

```
hex = IntegerString[#, 16]&;
```

and return `hex@hash` in the above function.